# Symfony2 Service Doctrine ManyToOne returns null

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I know there are a lot of questions like this one, but I assure you, I have passed last 6 hours looking for Internet how can I solve this, without success...

I am using Symfony2 controllers as a services, so I must send everything that I need to the `__construct` method of my controller.

I am trying to work with 2 Entities, one of them is "User" and the other one is "Department" (I attach the files content below) and I have repositories for each entity.

Inside the User Entity I am using the Doctrine `@ORM\ManyToOne` with the `@ORM\JoinColumn`, and inside the Department Entity I have the `@ORM\OneToMany`.

So, when I try to do this...

```
$department = $this->departmentRepository->find(1);
$users = $department->getUsers();
```

...I get an `ArrayCollection()`, but when I am doing this...

```
$user = $this->userRepository->find(1);
$department = $user->getDepartment();
```

... this method returns "null" instead of `Department()`

I have checked the MySQL table, and I assure you, the stored record inside "users" table has the ID of the department. So, I don't understand why is happening this...

This is the User Entity config, about the `@ORM\ManyToOne` and `@ORM\JoinColumn`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="`users`", options={"collate"="utf8_unicode_ci"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    // Here there are other properties

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Department", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="`department_id`", referencedColumnName="`id`", nullable=true)
     */
    private $department;

    // Here there are Getters and Setters
}
```

This is the Department Entity, about the @ORM\OneToMany:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="`departments`", options={"collate"="utf8_unicode_ci"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\DepartmentRepository")
 */
class Department
{
    // Here there are other properties

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="department")
     */
    private $users;

    // Here there are Getters and Setters, and the Constructor
}
```

And this is the UserController:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository;
// There are more "use", I have cleaned this source code

/**
 * @Route(service="app.user.controller")
 */
class UserController
{
    // There are more properties

    /**
     * @var UserRepository
     */
    private $userRepository;

    // There are a constructor with this:
    public function __constructor(UserRepository $userRepository) { $this->userRepository = $userRepository; }

    /**
     * There is a method to list all users (it works) but does not load the departments
     */
    public function listAction()
    {
        $users = $this->userRepository->findAll();
        exit(var_dump($users[0]->getDepartment()));
        return ['users' => $users];
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me, please?

Thank you mates,

Comment: Maybe clear the cache.  Verify that getDepartment() does not have a spelling error.  I suppose the back ticks might be doing something though they should be fine.

Comment: Yesterday I cleaned the Symfony2 cache several times, doing some tests about translations. This issue still not working. :(

Comment: Sorry to here that.  When I encounter these sorts of mysteries I'll often bring down a fresh project and then try to reproduce the problem with minimal additional code.  All I can think of is that you have some sort of doctrine filter (perhaps being used by a different bundle) that is somehow interfering.  Either that or you are making changes to one file but a different file is actually being used.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In fact, I don't understand why is happening this, because on my previous project all works fine, and I am applying the "same" configuration with the OneToMany and ManyToOne Doctrine annotations. If I cannot find the reason, maybe I will try to create a new project, and I will copy the source code, piece per piece, to find the error. If someone knows what can producing this error, please, I can save some time before "restart" the project, as Cerad has said. Thanks mate.

Comment: did anyone find anything. I'm also facing the same type of issue.

Comment: The only thing that worked for me when I was working on that project was building the Doctrine Queries manually through the Query Builder, including the Joins, Wheres and Parameters. All the lazy load feature was not working at all.